# Storing result from FOR loop as one array (array only saves each results separately)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have tried searching but can't find anything to help, maybe my problem is too simple! Anyway, I'm running an ajax request. The data given to the request is an array. Here is my code:

```
var id = "1#2#3#4#5#";
var chkdId = id.slice(0, -1);
var arr = chkdId.split('#');
var checkedId = '';
var chkdLen = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < chkdLen; i++) {
    checkedId = arr[i];
    var checkedId = checkedId;
    var data = {};
    var year = $('#year').val();
    data["year"] = year;
    data['type'] = "report";
    data['accidentId'] = checkedId;
    console.log(data);
    ajax.readData('/report/readreport', data, null,
        function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert('err ' + error);
        }
    );

}
```

request array:

```
Object {year:"2015" type: "report", accidentId: "1"}
Object {year:"2015" type: "report", accidentId: "2"}
Object {year:"2015" type: "report", accidentId: "3"}
Object {year:"2015" type: "report", accidentId: "4"}
Object {year:"2015" type: "report", accidentId: "5"}
```

result:

```
{"data":[{"name":aaaa,"age":"15"}]}
{"data":[{"name":bbb,"age":"25"}]}
{"data":[{"name":ccc,"age":"65"}]}
{"data":[{"name":ddd,"age":"45"}]}
{"data":[{"name":eee,"age":"24"}]}
```

How to store the results in a single array?

Comment: Does the API you are making an AJAX request to allow you to send a single object to it with all the data you need contained in it? If so, that might solve your problem right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/qfr68uvo/1/)

```
var id = "1#2#3#4#5#";
var chkdId = id.slice(0, -1);
console.log(chkdId);
var arr = chkdId.split('#');
var checkedId = '';
var chkdLen = arr.length;

// here is the array
var arrayWithResults = [];

for (var i = 0; i < chkdLen; i++) {
    checkedId = arr[i];
    var checkedId = checkedId;
    var data = {};
    var year = $('#year').val();
    data["year"] = year;
    data['type'] = "report";
    data['accidentId'] = checkedId;
    console.log(data);
    ajax.readData('/report/readreport', data, null,
        function (result) {
            console.log(result);

            // here you push in the requested data
            arrayWithResults.push(result);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert('err ' + error);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the `ajax` out of `for`. This will send only **One** ajax request to server and minimize the load on server.

```
var params = [];
for (var i = 0; i < chkdLen; i++) {
    checkedId = arr[i];
    var data = {};
    var year = $('#year').val();
    data["year"] = year;
    data['type'] = "report";
    data['accidentId'] = checkedId;


    params.push(data);
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

ajax.readData('/report/readreport', params, null,
//                                  ^^^^^^
    function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    function (error) {
        alert('err ' + error);
    }
);
```